# Firebase Cloud Firestore, How to receive only 4 document using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I am creating simple news app, using Nuxt.js and Firebase Cloud Firestore, I easily retrieve all document  data from a database, The problem is, I want to get a certain amount of data, exactly I want to retrive only 4 document from category `politics` collection,
[image]

```js
import { db } from "/plugins/firebase.js";
export const state = () => ({
    politicNews:[]
  })
  
  
  export const mutations = {
    politicNewsInfo(state, payload){
      state.politicNews.push(payload)
    }
  }
  
  
  export const actions = {
   async getAllpoliticInfo({commit}){
    /* get all  data  from politics collection*/
    const snapshot = await db.collection("politics").get();
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>
      commit("politicNewsInfo", { news: doc.data().News, newsId: doc.id })
    );
    }
  
  }
  
  export const getters = {

    politicinfoResults(state){
      return state.politicNews
    }
  
  }
```

This is what my Vuex store module looks like, I will get any advice, or documentary source, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve only a limited number of documents, you need two things:

- You need to tell the database to put the documents in a specific order.
- You then need to tell it to return only a certain number of documents.

```
db.collection("politics").orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()).limit(4).get()
```

Also see the documentation on [ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

Comment: what if, i want to call  next 4 document on button click, It is possible to implement this functionality?

Comment: You should [paginate the query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query).